# How to use environment variables for debugging in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am creating a plugin for swc. It fails and I was told to add an environment variable for debugging.
RUST_LOG=trace and SWC_DEBUG=1
Where should I put these variables? To what file? If I write them before "cargo test" - an error, an unrecognized command.
help me please

Comment: Environment variables are the responsibility of the operating system. If you're in a standard Bash shell, you can just write the environment variable assignment on the same line as your command and it'll work. On Windows, I believe you'll have to do the assignment on a different line in the same terminal (been awhile since I did any dev work on Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running your code on Unix, you need to add them in terminal right before execution command.

E.g.: `RUST_LOG=trace SWC_DEBUG=1 cargo test` or `RUST_LOG=trace SWC_DEBUG=1 ./my_program_name`.

If you running your code from Powershell on Windows, it is not so easy and requires 2 commands:

```
> $env:RUST_LOG="trace"
> $env:SWC_DEBUG=1
> cargo test
```

You may read more about them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Comment: Thank you! I set a variable in windows.
Can you please tell me where are the logs? Are they saved to a file or written to the console? I do not see anything

Comment: @Roman I don't really know, I just shown how to work with environmental variables in general but I don't know anything `swc` specific.